# How to post JSON body to an API with Basic Authentication using Java?

Tags: java, android, json, android-asynctask

I am calling Traccar API from my AsyncTask class. I need to pass JSON and Basic Authentication using POST method. I have this inside my doInBackground but it returns 400 Bad Request. I cannot pinpoint what's wrong. I'm pretty sure URL and credentials are all correct.

```
String credentials= "my_username:my_password";
                String credBase64 = Base64.encodeToString(credentials.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT).replace("\n", "");
                URL url = new URL("https://server.traccar.org/api/devices");
                HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
                urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", credBase64);
                if (this.postData!=null)
                {
                    OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
                    writer.write(this.postData.toString());
                    writer.flush();
                }

                int statusCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();
                if(statusCode == 200)
                {
                    InputStream inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
                    String response = inputStream.toString();
                }
                else
                {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Error"  + statusCode);
                }
```

Comment: what type of API are you using?

Comment: Hi Levi, its Traccar API

Comment: Yeah, I posted an answer that might be the reason you getting the 400 response